# Problem displaying data from datatable row's current object

Tags: jsf, datatable, primefaces

I have a problem with my datatable, I want display the information of a datatable's row  when selecting it, for that I created a value called currentChangerStatus I wanted to set it to the current selection, here is my code:

```
<p:dataTable id="projets"  var="p" value="#{projet.init()}" rowSelectListener="#{projet.currentChangerStatus(currentChangerStatus)}" selectionMode="single" onRowSelectStart="datecreation">  

                                    <f:facet name="header">  
                                            Listes des projets Gpsi  
                                        </f:facet>  

                                        <p:column>  
                                            <f:facet name="header">  
                                                <h:outputText value="Code" />  
                                            </f:facet>  
                                            <h:outputText value="#{p.projets.codeProjet}" />  
                                        </p:column>  

                                        <p:column>  
                                            <f:facet name="header">  
                                                <h:outputText value="Intitulé" />  
                                            </f:facet>  
                                            <h:outputText value="#{p.projets.libelle}" />  
                                        </p:column>  


                                    </p:dataTable>
```

the bean:

```
 public void setCurrentChangerStatus(ChangerStatus currentChangerStatus)
{
    this.currentChangerStatus=currentChangerStatus;
}
  public ChangerStatus getCurrentChangerStatus()
{
        return currentChangerStatus;
    }
```

the problem is that the datable is not accepting this expression :

```
rowSelectListener="#{projet.currentChangerStatus(currentChangerStatus)}"
```

Comment: _"please help because i need this project very soon!"_ - Please accept some answers (see the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is other way to display the information of a datatable's row.

```
<p:dataTable>
.....
.....
   <p:column>
    <p:commandLink update="xhtmlElementID" title="View Detail"  >
                     <p:graphicImage value="/images/search.png" />
                   <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{p}" target="#{project.SomeObject}" />
         </p:commandLink>
</p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

here target="#{project.SomeObject}"  is the Data to be updated when you cleck on command link

Comment: hey i founded the solution by adding nRowSelectUpdate="xhtmlElementID" to the datatable thanks all for your help

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using the row selection in a wrong way. The attribute `rowSelectListener` needs to point to a method with this signature (as to the [Primefaces showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableRowSelectionInstant.jsf)):

```
 public void onRowSelect(SelectEvent event) { ... }
```

In your `p:dataTable` you need to refer to this method this way:

```
<p:dataTable var="car" value="#{tableBean.cars}" paginator="true" rows="10"  
     selection="#{tableBean.selectedCar}" selectionMode="single"  
     rowSelectListener="#{tableBean.onRowSelect}"
```

Notice how the listener method is refered to.

With this you get the selected row object in `tableBean.selectedCar`.

A complete example is given in the showcase (link above).

**UPDATE** From your comments:

This is the problem:

```
value="#{projet.init()}"
```

The value attribute needs to refer to a list or something containing your data and not to a method. If you have for instance a class Project and want to display a list of projects in the table, your backing bean has to contain something like this:

```
private List<Project> projects;

public List<Project> getProjects() {
   return projects;
}

public void setProjects(List<Project> projects) {
   this.projects = projects;
}
```

In the [primefaces showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableRowSelectionSingle.jsf) its the `carSmall` list that does the same.

Comment: @Matt Handy i already tryed the primefaces's show case before posting my problem on here, when i try to call the onRowSelect on my page's code,i tape projet. then crtl+space and that gives me #{projet.onRowSelect(event)} if i delere (event) to have just #{projet.onRowSelect} the compiler tells me that the property onRowSelect is unkown. and also when i try to set current object selectedCar by #{projet.selectedCar} the page refer to the geter, and when i try to refer to the seter method it gives me #{{projet.setSelectedCar(selectedCar)}

Comment: @cascadox: Are you sure us use it exactly as in my answer? Which Primefaces version do you use? The fact that the compiler complains about a "property" is a bit irritating since the `rowSelectListener` attribute must resolve to a method and not to a property. Please add some code to your answer that shows the changes you made.

Comment: @Matt Handy: yeah i did as on the showcase here is my code:

<p:dataTable id="projets"  var="p" value="#{projet.init()}" selection="#{projet.currentChangerStatus}" rowSelectListener="#{projet.onRowSelect(event)}" onRowSelectUpdate="datecreation" selectionMode="single" onRowSelectComplete="datecreation">  
..............
</f:facet>  
                                        </p:dataTable>

Comment: and here is the backup bean :

public void onRowSelect(SelectEvent event){
        currentChangerStatus = (ChangerStatus)event.getObject();
         FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("project Selected", ((ChangerStatus) event.getObject()).getEtats().getLibelleEtat());  
  
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
    
}

Comment: @Matt Handy:normaly when i select i row,the application should set the currentobject and display a message with the value getLibelleEtat() but it's not working...

Comment: @cascadox: Updated my answer. The value attribte is the problem.

Comment: @Matt Handy:thanks for your time, but here is my init method:

public List<ChangerStatus>  init()
    {
       return changerStatusService.getAllChangerStatus();
    }

as you can see it returns a list, and it's working on the datatable, the problem is i can't display the data from row on labels on a panelgrid for exemple

Comment: @cascadox: Ok, that the table is displayed is one thing. But you use it the wrong way and this is beyond jsf specification. So even if you see the table you easily get errors later (and this is what you experience). Change your list to be a correct bean property as described in the showcase and in my answer and then try again to add row selection.